# How to post a collection to WebApi using Restangular.Js

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, restangular

This get posted to the server as `departments` are `null`

JavaScrtipt code:

```
var departments = [{ DepartmentName : "Name", DepartmentId : 1}];
Restangular.all('records/StartNewDate').post(departments);
```

Web Api Controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage StartNewDate(DepartmentViewModel[] departments)
{
  ....
  ....
}
```

Server Model

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Post what the payload is over wire. Look in chrome dev console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to JSON.stringify the object before you send it in the payload:

```
 return Restangular.all('records/StartNewDate').post(JSON.stringify(departments));
```